# Active Menu Include php

Tags: php, menu, include, request

First of all, i would like to mention that i know that there are multiple topics on this matter.

yet i decided to make my own version as a form of learning and there are several reasons i need to learn it this way.

The error i recieve is this one: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.php'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in D:\xampp\htdocs\school\Oktober\inc\menu2.php on line 24

The key here is i would primarly like to learn to use links more effectively in my systems, it would be of great help if someone would be able to help me out here.

Result: A included dynamic menu based on the URL.

```
    <?php

// pages
$menupages = array(
    'Home',
    'Over Ons',
    'Verkoopcijfers',
    'Koop Nu',
);

// output
?>
<nav class="menu-main">
    <ul>
<?php

// loop
foreach ( $menupages as $menupage )
{
    // convert page name to url
    $menupageurl = strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '-', $menupageurl ) );
    // find active url
    $active = '';
    if ( '/'.$menupageurl'.php' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) $active = ' active';
    // output
?>
        <li><a href="<?=$menupageurl?>.php" class="<?=$active?>"><?=$menupage?></a></li>

<?php
}

?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your syntax:

```
'/'.$menupageurl'.php
```

is not valid - your string concatenation is wrong. It should be

```
'/'.$menupageurl.'.php
```